# How to allocate vector size of any Gb in R studio

Tags: r, memory-management

I am trying to run this code in R studio,

```
set.seed(224)
data_combined_r_valid <- forecastML::calculate_intervals(data_combined_r, data_residuals_valid,
                                                         levels = c(.50, .80, .95), times = 100L)

plot(data_combined_r_valid)
```

I am constantly getting the error

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 5.8 Gb
```

I have tried the following code as suggested,

```
memory.size()
memory.limit()
memory.limit(size=56000)
```

Can anyone please help me out to rectify this error even after trying out what was suggested.
Thank you.

Comment: How much RAM is on your computer?

Comment: R tries to write a vector of 5.8Gb, but it has (at that time!) nog enough free memory to do so. There are (many) more topics with the same problem on SO, read them. Also, check page 15 of the R inferno (free pdf, google it).